# Given an imported module, how can I determine the import path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python function that takes a imported module as a parameter:

```
def printModule(module):
    print("That module is named '%s'" % magic(module))

import foo.bar.baz
printModule(foo.bar.baz)
```

What I want is to be able to extract the module name (in this case `foo.bar.baz`) from a passed reference to the module. In the above example, the `magic()` function is a stand-in for the function I want.

`__name__` would normally work, but that requires executing in the context of the passed module, and I'm trying to extract this information from merely a reference to the module.

What is the proper procedure here?

<strike>All I can think of is either doing `string(module)`, and then some text hacking, or trying to inject a function into the module that I can then call to have return `__name__`, and neither of those solutions is elegant.</strike> (I tried both these, neither actually work. Modules can apparently permute their name in the `string()` representation, and injecting a function into the module and then calling it just returns the caller's context.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "requires executing in the context of the passed module", ``__name__`` seems to work even if ``magic()`` is defined in a separate module

Comment: @fjarri - I can't modify the module (all I have is a reference at runtime). I tried injecting a function into the module namespace, but it still returns `__main__`. How else would you do this? It would work if I could modify the module to include a function that returns `__name__`, but that would require modifying every module on my system.

Comment: Umm, ``magic = lambda m: m.__name__``. Or am I not understanding something?

Comment: import os
>>> print os.__file__
C:\Python27\lib\os.pyc

Comment: @AbhishekGoswami - No

Comment: @fjarri: `>>> import os.path
>>> print(os.path.__name__)
ntpath` - Name is no-go, it's not the import path. (it also changes - it's `posixpath` on *nix)

Comment: Works with ``logging.config`` or ``numpy.random`` though.

Comment: P.S. ``os.path`` is a **variable** with the value of ``posixpath`` or ``ntpath``, that's why ``__name__`` does not work.

Comment: @fjarri - Arrrgh, so of course, I try the worst possible test case. Derp. `sys.modules['os.path'] = path`

Comment: @fjarri - Can you make "just use `__name__`" an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__name__` attribute seems to work:

```
def magic(m):
    return m.__name__
```

Comment: Note: `os.path` does some modification of `sys.modules`, which was causing it to not work *on that particular module*, which was confusing the hell out of me.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a string with the module name, you can use pkgutil.

```
import pkgutil
pkg = pkgutil.get_loader(module_name)
print pkg.fullname
```

From the module itself,

```
import pkgutil
pkg = pkgutil.get_loader(module.__name__)
print pkg.fullname
```

Comment: I only have a reference to the module. If I had the filename, that would be easy. Did you read the question?

Comment: It is not the file name but the module name

Comment: I'm trying to recover the module name from a reference to the module. This answer is useless.

Comment: `>>> import pkgutil
>>> import os.path
>>> pkg = pkgutil.get_loader(os.path.__name__)
>>> pkg.fullname
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'SourceFileLoader' object has no attribute 'fullname'`